How to left align author in R quarto to pdf with template partials?
For my .qmd I want to change part of the pdf template. I ran into some challenges. Anyone an idea?

Left align title and subtitle: I managed that with changes to partial title.tex
Left align author: unfortunately did not work the same way. How then?
I want a left aligned image placed before the title, how? I was thinking on before-title.tex, but keep getting error messages about missing \begin document.
I want a short left aligned text placed before the title, how?
When I relocate the toc, the links are shown in hyperlink blue, when I keep the original location it looks better (the regular black). How can I have the toc on the place I want, but keep (or get back) the original color?

A small example with a qmd, tex and an image is on https://github.com/MMJansen/Partial. Thanks for your help!

I did something similar, but didn't use template partials. You can re-define the title that is created when you add \maketitle (this can include add title like elements e.g. title, author, date, ... e.g.
% left align title and author
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketitle}{\bgroup\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\begin{flushleft}
  {\sffamily\huge\textbf{\MakeUppercase{\@title}}} \vspace{0.3cm} \newline
  {\Large {\@subtitle}} \newline
  \@author
\end{flushleft}\egroup
}
\makeatother

In the Quarto document, add this in
pdf:
  include-in-header: 
    - "title.tex"
  toccolor: "blue"

You can change the colour of the TOC links using toccolor argument to any color you want.

Thanks Nicola! The code in the first block when placed in a file "title.tex" works! Author is also to the left. toccolor seems to work fine when the toc is in the original place (toc: true), but not on another place(toc: false and in the body \tableofcontents)

Does the solution here (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88400/hyperref-changing-the-linkcolor-locally-in-the-toc) work for changing it when using \tableofcontents?

Yes! Thank you! Not exactly like there, but only a slight change was needed. When using \hypersetup{linkcolor=black} before the \tableofcentents, the toc got color black. For people wanting to recreate, have \usepackage{hyperref} in the YAML.
